# How do I know if my SSD Drive supports TRIM?

Tags: windows-7, ssd

Windows 7 has support for the TRIM command which should help ensure that the performance of an SSD drive remains good through it's life.

How can you tell if a given SSD drive supports TRIM?

See [here](http://www.anandtech.com/storage/showdoc.aspx?i=3531&p=10) for a description of TRIM.

Also the following from a Microsoft presentation:

> Microsoft implementation of “Trim” feature is supported in Windows 7 
>   NTFS will send down delete notification to the device supporting “trim”
>   File system operations:  Format, Delete, Truncate, Compression
>   OS internal processes:  e.g., Snapshot, Volume Manager 
>   Three optimization opportunities for the device 
>   Enhancing device wear leveling by eliminating merge operation for all deleted data blocks
>   Making early garbage collection possible for fast write 
>   Keeping device’s unused storage area as much as possible; more room for device wear leveling.

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion it'll show up under "Capabilities" in the details tab for the device in device manager, or perhaps somewhere in /proc if you boot a linux CD.  Despite searching around, though, I'm not finding much.  I do know there has been chatter on LKML about detecting TRIM support and enabling optimizations recently...

Comment: This really is a very useful question. Searching around i see many people wonder if TRIM is working, or enabled, or if their device has it, or is a firmware upgrade will include it. But there's no way to know for sure if it's working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An answer to this question was published in the comments section on the [Engineering 7 blog post about SSD and Windows 7](http://blogs.msdn.com/e7/archive/2009/05/05/support-and-q-a-for-solid-state-drives-and.aspx).

To find out if Windows 7 is sending the TRIM command you can run the following command from an elevated prompt:

```
>fsutil behavior query DisableDeleteNotify
```

and how to interpret this [based on a comment](http://blogs.msdn.com/e7/archive/2009/05/05/support-and-q-a-for-solid-state-drives-and.aspx#9594848).

> "...if fsutil reports that
>   "DisableDeleteNotify" is 0, then Trim
>   is enabled.  (The feature is sometimes
>   referred to using different names: 
>   Trim == Delete Notification == Unused
>   Clusters Hint.)  The setting is
>   written in terms of disabling
>   something because we like to use
>   values of 0 for defaults.
>
> Have Trim enabled according to this
>   setting, which you do, means that the
>   filesystem will send Trim commands
>   down the storage stack.  The
>   filesystem doesn't actually know
>   whether this command will be supported
>   or not at a lower level.  When the
>   disk driver receives the command, it
>   will either act on it or ignore it. 
>   If you know for sure that your storage
>   devices don't support Trim, you could
>   go ahead and disable Trim (enable
>   DisableDeleteNotify) so the filesystem
>   won't bother to send down these
>   notifications.  However sending down
>   the notifications is pretty
>   lightweight and I haven't seen any
>   performance improvement by disabling
>   them, so I don't recommend disabling
>   this setting.  If you have an SSD
>   which does support Trim, then you
>   definitely don't want to disable it,
>   because there are some performance
>   gains to be had for leaving the
>   setting in its default form."

It seems that this still won't tell you if the drive and or firmware for the drive supports TRIM. Sigh.

Comment: This isn’t very useful. `fsutil` only tells you that your filesystem supports TRIM (and that no one has manually disabled it). We already know that. See illmortal’s answer below to find out if TRIM is actually enabled on your drive.

Comment: I have weird situation on my SSD with TRIM enabled feature, there are old files that can be restored. Have no clue how it can be. I have disk optimization scheduled for each week to issue Trimming (default Windows 10 setup). I even forced Trimming, but old files can still be restored via Recuva tool.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to know if your SSD supports TRIM is to use [CrystalDiskInfo](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html).

Answer (score 7):

Download and install the [Intel SSD Toolbox](http://www.intel.com/support/go/ssdtoolbox/index.htm).

If your drive is not an Intel SSD, the only option available will be **View Drive Information**. Click that.
Scroll down to

> **Word `169`**, **Bit 0 - Data Set Management Supported**

If this is **`1`**, you have `TRIM`. If **`0`**, you don't.

[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Sending the disabledeletenotify command to the SSD only checks if the TRIM command is being sent. The drive, of course, needs to support TRIM. The best way of doing that is to go to the manufacturer's website and check in the detailed spec for your drive.

Answer (score 0):

[Samsung Magician](http://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/product/consumer/magician.html) is available only for Windows and provides information about ACHI and TRIM support by your current setup for Sumsung genuine SSD.

Do not forget to enable periodic drive optimization under `dfrgui.exe`. For SSD drive that mean to issue TRIM commands on unused blocks.

Answer (score -1):

A bit late and also for the wrong OS, but on Windows 10 Build 21H2 (Windows 7 not tested, other versions of Windows 10 may have different syntax), you could check, if a volume on a single disk supports trim, by starting a manual trim and look for the result.

In an administrative command prompt enter (please vary drive letter):

```
defrag c: /retrim
```

Performing this for volume on a HW RAID (a single disk from the point of view of Windows which definitively does not support TRIM without special drivers), it gives me

```
Microsoft Drive Optimizer
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corp.

Invoking retrim on (E:)...

        Retrim:  100% complete.

The operation requested is not supported by the hardware backing the volume. (0x8900002A)
```

whereas on my system disk it gives me

```
Microsoft Drive Optimizer
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corp.

Invoking retrim on (C:)...


The operation completed successfully.

Post Defragmentation Report:

        Volume Information:
                Volume size                 = 465.15 GB
                Free space                  = 422.79 GB

        Retrim:
                Total space trimmed         = 422.58 GB
```

Unfortunately, this command does not set the errorlevel, so if you want to process the result programmatically, you must parse the output and this is language dependent.

BTW: This command can be executed if `DisableDeleteNotify` is enabled or not.

But wait... This would be too easy. I have a Striped Volume (software RAID in Windows consisting of several disks), and have `DisableDeleteNotify` set to `0` (i.e. TRIM is generally enabled), the command above gives me the result "not supported by the hardware". But I have seen effects that the disks in the volume are busy for several minutes writing to `$Log` and `$Mft`. After setting `DisableDeleteNotify`  to `1`, these effects were gone. So I think these disks were trimmed, no matter what that command above said.