# How to manually trim an SSD in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, ssd

I would like to manually trim my SSD in Windows 7. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this thread...http://superuser.com/questions/64121/ssd-and-trim-on-windows7

Comment: And this one...http://superuser.com/questions/145697/how-do-i-know-if-my-ssd-drive-supports-trim

Comment: Can't find steps in both questions on how to issue a TRIM manually.

Comment: What kind of SSD?

Comment: OCZ vertex turbo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some SSD manufacturers have provided utilities on their websites that allow you to perform a "TRIM" like function manually. Check yours and see if it has that.

Answer (score 6):

I wrote an [article](http://ticksontech.blogspot.com/2011/12/trim-for-masses_10.html) about TRIM; it also refers to a tool to manually TRIM your SSD: ForceTrim ([download ForceTrim.zip](http://www.mediafire.com/download/1cd8dh0msw2jq1w/ForceTrim.zip), scan report at [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/25bc0f6d582e97ef2fa10efec315ecd774184e865055931dd84a02641337fafc/analysis/1412334262/)).

OCZ's forum is gone, but an archived version of *Here's a tool to force-TRIM your entire drive* is [available](http://web.archive.org/web/20120530102049/http://www.ocztechnologyforum.com/forum/showthread.php?73888-Here-s-a-tool-to-force-TRIM-your-entire-drive). The source code is unfortunately lost.

Comment: The source code is unfortunately lost, but it appears that the tool writes `<DRIVELETTER>:\_TRIM_`, invokes TRIM on that and then removes it again.

Comment: I have the source code if you need, I remember the original thread a few years ago and having checked the source code, it's made in Delphi.

Comment: Please, would love to have that.

Comment: @JamesKing I know this is ancient, but any chance either of you were able to find the source code for this?

Comment: You can also use any tool that wipes free space on the drive (as long as it does so by filling the drive with a file / files then deleting it / them); should have the same result as a side-effect; assuming the system is configured to TRIM files on delete.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit old but want to add: As an alternative, most tools with a generic "wipe free space" feature will have the same effect that ForceTrim did assuming that the system is properly configured to TRIM files on delete.

Most wipes are implemented by filling up the drive with a file, writing the wipe pattern to it, then deleting it. If your wiping tool of choice does it this way, the delete(s) should trigger a TRIM on all the space the wipe file(s) used.

I know CCleaner does it but you can find other tools on Google or whatever.

Theoretically, this applies to any platform and any drive model, again, assuming TRIM-friendly system configuration.