# Manually trimming unused NTFS SSD blocks in windows after imaging drive

Tags: windows-10, ssd, ntfs, trim

I upgraded my SSD by dd'ing the old drive to a new drive under Linux.  This has the side effect of also copying "empty space."

Is there a way to ask Windows to trim the NTFS unused blocks?  Other than filling up the drive with a giant file and removing it?  On Linux we would use `fstrim`.

Closest existing question I could find was this one that points to vendor tools that trims the whole drive, or a tool that simply fills the drives and removes the file:

[How to manually trim an SSD in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/203956/how-to-manually-trim-an-ssd-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [Optimize-Volume](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/optimize-volume?view=win10-ps) cmdlet in an elevated powershell:

```
PS C:\>Optimize-Volume -DriveLetter H -ReTrim -Verbose
```

Additional references:  https://winaero.com/blog/trim-ssd-windows-10/