# NTFS : The requested operation could not be completed due to a file system limitation

Tags: windows, filesystems, windows-server-2008, ntfs

In my OCZ 240GB PCI-Express SSD, I create huge files and after write about two files 45GB and 45GB the software throw exception "The requested operation could not be completed due to a file system limitation" While there are a lot of space out there.

I tried to investigate the problem, and some people said it maybe fragmentation problem. I tried to solve it by remove all the files from this partition so append in the huge files will not make fragmentation but the problem still there.

In this partition I have 40 files, two big (The files I try to creates) and the other files small (meta data) and the there are 6 fragmented files, and total file fragments is 3768243 - This information from defrag /v

I have Windows Server 2008 R2 - is there is any advice?

Comment: Is compression enabled on the SSD drive? If the files are copied from another drive, are the files compressed at the source?

Comment: Make sure you have TRIM enabled, see [Does having TRIM enabled affect other hard drives on a computer (and how do you know when Windows is using it)?](http://superuser.com/questions/229251/does-having-trim-enabled-affect-other-hard-drives-on-a-computer-and-how-do-you-k)

Comment: How are you writing these files out? Robocopy I assume?