# Does TRIM work under Windows 7 using NForce Raid and SSD drives?

Tags: ssd, raid, trim, nvidia-nforce

I can't seem to find a straight answer.

I've got a motherboard with an Nvidia 780SLI chipset.  I've installed the latest Nforce RAID drivers, and installed Windows 7 running on a pair of Crucial C300 in RAID 0.

1. Does this setup support TRIM?
2. If so, how do I detect/activate TRIM?

Answer (score 2):

[This post](https://web.archive.org/web/20100928035500/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/e7/archive/2009/05/05/support-and-q-a-for-solid-state-drives-and.aspx#comments) on MSDN has some comments from somebody at Microsoft that appears to indicate that TRIM might work and that it depends on the controller.

I had previously always thought the answer to this question was no.

Comment: Technically, it's possible that they could, if the RAID controller were SSD-aware and could correctly pass the TRIM commands down to the individual drives.  However, I'm not aware of any consumer or enthusiast level RAID implementations that actually do that.  Right now, for the OP's situation, the answer is "No."

Comment: To my knowledge, only some Intel raid controllers are fully SSD aware. Including Intel's "Rapid Storage Technology" (i.e. their chipset integrated controllers). https://www.anandtech.com/show/6161/intel-brings-trim-to-raid0-ssd-arrays-on-7series-motherboards-we-test-it

Answer (score 0):

No, it [does not](https://blog.thecybershadow.net/2012/12/09/ssd-trim-check-tool/#hashover-c1r2) support TRIM. Currently the only drivers supporting TRIM are Microsoft's own storage drivers, Intel's, and [AMD's](http://www.rage3d.com/board/showthread.php?threadid=33970627).

And only [selected](https://superuser.com/questions/139804/is-trim-supported-on-raid-0-configurations-for-ssd-drives-in-windows-7) controllers support TRIMing an SSD that is in a RAID array.

While the C300 drives are very fast, the build in garbage collection is not very aggressive, so without TRIM you will get a significant drop in write performance. I would recommend that, rather than running them in a RAID 0 you have them separate and spread out the IO load by installing stuff to both of 'em. This would allow you to use Microsoft's own drivers and so get TRIM.