# How can I optimize the speed and lifetime of SSDs used in a RAID-0?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, raid-0

I have two SSDs in RAID-0 on a Windows 7, 64-bit system.  Since it [appears that TRIM still isn't supported](https://superuser.com/questions/139804/is-trim-supported-on-raid-0-configurations-for-ssd-drives-in-windows-7) with any RAID configuration of SSDs, what are some tips/workarounds that I can use?

Some things, but not limited to, that I would like to optimize are:

- file write sizes to each disk to best match each 'block' sizes that are erased by the SSD.
- speed of the RAID reads/writes
- overall health of the drives
- Settings of the RAID (i.e. stripe size)
- any other 'tips' that might be considered for a RAID of SSD's

Comment: No idea, why not post them over to me and I am sure I can work some things out :)

Comment: I'm curious about why you need two SSDs in RAID 0 in the first place. To aggregate the space for convenience? Improved sequential access? I know this really doesn't help answer your question, but my tip would be not to do this.

Comment: @Sblair this was done originally as a test to see if there was a significant increase in speed for a [blog post](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/03/25/the-king-of-kings-ssd-testing-part-2/).  As there was, the thought was/is that one could purchase two smaller, less-expensive SSD's, then RAID them and get a faster experience cheaper.  Yes, you can expect this to be blogged in the future. ;)

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest not using RAID0 for good SSDs. A good modern SSD is unlikely to be your bottleneck for most real-world access patterns, at least not in a way RAID-0 is going to help a lot.

Unless of course you are linking a pair of drives together this way in order to have one large volume rather than two separate ones, rather than due to speed concerns...

Some SSD controllers will take writing a block of all 0s to mean that the block is free to be TRIMed (and instead of storing the location of the block in the appropriate index store a sentinel value that means "if you are asked for this block, just return a load of 0s"). If your drives do this then occasionally writing over your free space with 0s would help, using [sdelete](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897443) or similar in zero-only mode. Not terribly efficient of course, and make sure your drives will react this way otherwise you will be making the situation worse rather than better.

Comment: The goal is to be able to have two cheaper, smaller spaced drives that give me more space but not as expensive

Comment: In that case you'll need to look into if those drives auto-trim for all-zero blocks as described above. Also make sure you have a good backup regime as you are increasing your chance of drive failure noticeably over that of a single drive configuration.

Comment: For info, [this post](http://superuser.com/questions/283590/restoring-ssd-performance-of-a-used-ssd-drive/283592#283592) describes how to "zero" an entire SSD, under Windows.

Comment: Raid 0 on SSD drives is a bad idea IMO. 2x the chance of data loss.