# How to speed up an old external SSD

Tags: ssd, external-hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Restoring performance and estimating life of a used SSD drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/283590/restoring-performance-and-estimating-life-of-a-used-ssd-drive)

I have a small (32GB) external SSD that I use for quick backup between work and home. It gets a couple of GB rewritten every day, for the last year or so, and I have noticed it has slowed down recently.

What is the best way to restore it to full speed? Is it enough to just delete everything on the drive and copy it back on again, or should I reformat it or something similar? Thanks!

Comment: You do understand that a SSD has a limited number of writes that it supports.  A couple GB a days ( lets say 3.5GB ) would be 1,277.5GB worth of data in a year.  The reason your drive is slowing down is because there are likely bad sectors and working a great deal not to make them permenantly unwritable.  STOP USING YOUR SSD IN THIS WAY.

Comment: Well, that is what the SSD is for... So I will accept lower speeds if I must, but stopping using it for its purpose seems like overkill :). Anyway, I thought that the write limit was closer to 10 years at that kind of rate. Could be wrong.