# SSD shuts off after minutes of use, only hard reboot detects it again

Tags: ssd, freeze

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 8 Killed my SSDs](https://superuser.com/questions/497284/windows-8-killed-my-ssds)

I've been using a SSD (M4 Crucial) for quite a while now as my main partition using Windows 7. Set to AHCI and making sure TRIM etc is enabled in Windows it was running smoothly for months up to today.

I did not make any changes to the system (do all updates etc manually), however every 20-30mins (irregularly though but it works fine the first minutes after boot) the SSD does not seem to respond anymore (I can see the cursor of the mouse moving but overall the OS freezes because of the SSD) and eventually the system restarts itself.

Then, upon restart and when the BIOS detects the drives and lists the AHCI connected SSD drive the SSD does not show up, so the system won't restart.

However, when I do a hard reboot and shut the power off and back on the drive gets detected and the system boots normally until above happens again. I've tested this around a dozen times already and it **always boots normally when doing a hard reboot**.

It looks like the drive is going into some kind of sleep mode and shuts itself off though I have no sleep functionality enabled, neither in BIOS nor in Windows 7.

I also tried disabling AHCI completely and let the SSD run in IDE mode (keeping TRIM enabled in W7) but the problem persists so it doesn't seem like it's the AHCI drivers per se.

Any idea where to look and how to resolve this?

I could update the SSD drivers and mainboard (should there be any updates) but as I said it never ever had any problems before today, was running smoothly 100%, no crashes, no freezes.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a firmware bug in the SSD that makes it break after 5184 hours of uptime.

[Update the firmware](http://www.crucial.com/support/firmware.aspx) and it will start working.
(this will not affect your data)

Comment: I love you! Makes sense, just read through the firmware changelog...