# Testing Crucial SSD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I looked and did not find any SSD Hard Drive checking tools for Crucial like there are for other drives. Is there a way to test Crucial hard drives for failures other than SMART data?

I've done 2 fresh installs of Windows now on this drive and they end up not booting after a month. There is hardly anything installed on these systems so I find it hard to believe that updates and other aspects are crashing this system.

The drive is under 2000 power on hours so it is still very new.

I would like to know if this drive is still usable or not.

```
SMART

ID

Description

Current Value

Units


1 Raw Read Error Rate 0 Errors/Page 
5 Retired NAND Blocks 0 NAND Blocks 
9 Power On Hours Count 1854 Hours 
12 Power Cycle Count 70 Cycles 
171 Program Fail Count 0 NAND Page Program Failures 
172 Erase Fail Count 0 NAND Block Erase Failures 
173 Average Block-Erase Count 2 Erases 
174 Unexpected Power Loss Count 14 Unexpected Power Loss events 
180 Unused reserved block count 2159 Blocks 
183 SATA Interface Downshift 0 Downshifts 
184 Error Correction Count 0 Correction Events 
187 Reported Uncorrectable Errors 0 ECC Correction Failures 
194 Enclosure Temperature 35 Current Temperature (C) 
 59 Highest Lifetime Temperature (C) 
196 Reallocation Event Count 0 Events 
197 Current Pending Sector Count 0 512 Byte Sectors 
198 SMART Off-line Scan Uncorrectable Errors 0 Errors 
199 Ultra-DMA CRC Error Count 0 Errors 
202 Percentage Lifetime Used 0 % Lifetime Used 
206 Write Error Rate 0 Program Fails/MB 
210 RAIN Successful Recovery Page Count 0 TUs successfully recovered by RAIN 
246 Cumulative Host Write Sector Count 747622828 512 Byte Sectors 
247 Host Program Page Count 23638805 NAND Page 
248 FTL Program Page Count 32754520 NAND Page
```

The drive can be accessed just fine via a live CD or via SATA cable.

Latest FIRMWARE

MX100

The issue the happens is Windows gets the black screen not able to boot. I've tried startup repair and other options but Windows never boots backup so I've had to resort to reinstalling on a formatted drive.

Comment: I was about to suggest [this](http://superuser.com/a/467807/83694), but then I realized that I shouldn't be living in the past.  Is your SSD's firmware updated?  What does S.M.A.R.T. show?  What is the model of the drive?  What boot error(s) do you receive?  Can you access data on the SSD using a Linux LiveCD?  The more information you can provide, the better we can troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: Helpful to know more about the "they end up not booting after a month" let us solve the problem not the symptom.  There are dozens of tools designed to test the speed and health of SSD that work for any SSD.