# Save a failing solid-state drive?

Tags: ssd

I have a solid state drive I'm using for the OS + swap (mac os 10.6.8).  Recently, I've seen an increasing rate of kernel panics.  If I reboot and run Disk Utility, I can repair the drive, and I get messages about the number of directories being different.  Of course, I can only repair when booting from an alternative source.

Is there any way to pre-emptively identify when bad sectors are going to arise and prevent the kernel panics, thereby squeezing a few extra months out of the dying drive?  Or do I just need to replace the drive ASAP and pray I don't lose any more data in the meantime?

(FYI for those keeping stats: SSD was installed 11/2011, failures began 3/2013, was used as swap drive)

Comment: Is there any way to extend the life of the drive *without* wiping it?

Comment: Personally, I haven't found any yet.

Answer (score 0):

One method that has been recommended many times is the "[Secure Erase](https://superuser.com/a/283608/4464)" method.

The original question: [Restoring performance and estimating life of a used SSD drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/283590/restoring-performance-and-estimating-life-of-a-used-ssd-drive)