# How to securely erase ssd?

Tags: ssd, secure-erase

I want to sell my pc but I want to delete everything on my SSD without being recoverable. How to do that. It's SATA 3 500 MB/S KINGSTON.

[image]

Comment: More on the subject>>>>https://superuser.com/questions/1060831/triming-as-alternative-to-securely-erasing-a-ssd?rq=1

Answer (score -2):

Click on Start menu and type cmd.exe. Run it as Administrator - click on on application right mouse button and select to Run as Administrator. Then type

```
format <ssd drive letter>: /fs:NTFS /p:3
```

for example

```
format d: /fs:NTFS /p:3
```

The switch /p:3 means that all data will be destroyed 3 times and sectors with data will be filled by zeros or random numbers. It is pretty securely.

Comment: This will create completly unnecessary full drive writes (with the drive wear it brings).

Comment: Yes it is but it solution for securely wiping data from SSD. When you are remove files/folders then physically doesn't wipe it. I mean removing data by the press Remove item from right mouse button doesn't mean that after a couple of hours Idle files gone and can't be restored.

Comment: I said "discard" - which has nothing to do with a right mouse butto or an explorer window. It translates into a SATA command ("TRIM"), that tells the drive firmware, that the data in this range of sectors is no longer needed, which instructs the firmware to erase the cells as to prepare them for the next write.

Comment: And shooting the drive with a shotgun is also a "solution for securely wiping data from SSD". Marginally worse than `format /p`