# Combining SSDs using RAID-0

Tags: ssd, raid, raid-0

If I have 2 SSDs via SATA3, both reaching speeds of about 500MB/s, which is close to SATA3 limit, does it make sense to combine them using RAID0? I mean if the SATA3  chip can provide the 6Gb/s speed for all devices separately, there should be an improvement, right? Any experiences?

Comment: What RAID hardware/software/system are you using for this?

Comment: I'm using ASUS PRIME X299-DELUXE with i9 on Win 10.

Comment: What size are the SSDs?

Comment: 1TB samsung & trancend

Answer (score 2):

> does it make sense to combine them using RAID0?

**No.** The complexity of setting this up outweighs its usefulness.

If you want to achieve a major speed increase, upgrade to a motherboard with a new M.2 slot and put in an appropriate M.2 SSD.

A current - and not that expensive - Samsung M.2 SSD achieves a maximum reading speed of 3.4GB/s - far more that a RAID-0 of two SSDs with 500MB/s can achieve.

Concerning the problem of the TRIM-command and a SSD RAID-0 [this SuperUser question may add further information](https://superuser.com/q/139804/427002).

Comment: I actually have 2 M.2s here :), I just happen to have also 2 normal SSDs, one of them is redundant now, so I'm thinking if it would be useful somehow.

Comment: That's an unusual setup. I also own a X299 mobo :-) For usefulness, I would prefer data security over the possible speed of a RAID-0, unless you have special purposes.

Comment: You are probably right :)